# printing the precision from a confusion matrix in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

This is what I am getting.

```
       0    1
 0  [[102  39]
 1   [ 73  29]]
```

How can I just print the fraction `29/(29+39)`, meaning the precision of my confusiin matrix?

Comment: Take a look at [`sklearn.metrics.precision_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

what you  need is  [classification report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) from sklearn 
.

it's said that it returns:

> Text summary of the precision, recall, F1 score for each class.

here is an example :

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
y_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
target =["yes", "no"]
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target))
```

and the output :

[image]

Comment: Please also add the example usage also, to make this a good answer. Currently it seems link-only answer which is not encouraged here.