# How can I know the labels of my predicted classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I have trained my classifier on 3 dialects using text classification. And this was the confusion matrix and precision:

confusion matrix

```
[[27  6  0 16]
 [ 5 18  0 21]
 [ 1  3  6  9]
 [ 0  0  0 48]]
```

The precision

```
[0.81818182 0.66666667 1.         0.5106383 ]
```

How to know which row in the confusion matrix and which element in the precision belong to what dialect I have? I provided the training data to the classifier with the following labels :

```
Egyptian
Sudan
Iraqi
Jordan
```

Here's the code, I used RandomForestClassifier:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=0)  
classifier.fit(X, labels)  
test_pred = classifier.predict(y)
precision_score(labels_test,test_pred,average=None)
```

output:

```
array([0.91024735, 0.94929397, 0.98622273, 0,95343322])
```

Comment: The outputs will be in the same order as the input labels. So however you encoded the labels, ordinally or one-hot, the same transformer can be applied in reverse to your output labels

Comment: Maybe this will help. Also I think as the above comment says, it's in the same order as the input you gave to the classifier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792803/printing-the-precision-from-a-confusion-matrix-in-python

Comment: @G.Anderson But the input labels are shuffled. I have one csv file that has all 4 labels, how to know which one I gave it first?

Comment: How did you transform your text labels into numeric labels? What method or function did you call?

Comment: @G.Anderson I didn't transform them, they're string labels. I shuffled the training data and then passed them to the classifier

Comment: What classifier are you using? Can you show some of your code?

Comment: I used randomforest, okay, I will post the code

Comment: @G.Anderson I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classifier.classes_` will give you the labels the classifier is scoring on in the order they are stored in the classifier object. That should be the same order as the outputs you've already got, though I would verify that with some spot-checking of your predictions to be sure

Comment: What do you mean spot-checking of my predictions?

Comment: I counted the numbers of each row in the confusion matrix, and then opened an excel sheet of the test labels and counted each label to match it with the numbers in the confusion matrix.

Comment: What I meant was to do `classifier.predict_proba()`, which will return the class probabilities as, e.g., `[0.8, 0.1, 0. , 0.1]` and compare to `classifer.predict()`for a few samples and see if the class with the highest predicted class is the correct class in the assumed order. Just one more way to verify your assumptions.